# 3D circular motion Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d

I'm coding circular motion in *Matlab*, what is the appropriate formula or technique for circular motion in *3D-space*, however I make this phenomena by the circle equation of sin and cos but it just rotates the object in circular motion (object itself) without taking its *center*, I want rotation with *center of circle*.

**My Code:**

```
for ii = 1:3

circular motion = [5*sin(ii) 5 5*cos(ii)];
%I used gain of 5 in order to give its speed.
%matrix circular motion contains XYZ coordinates.

end
```

**Real life scenario of circular motion about center of circle:**
[image: Helicopter]

*Any suggestions or piece of formula that makes my strings unique are welcomed.*

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. What is it that you want to achieve? Also, what do you mean by "circular motion in 3D space" and "I want rotation with center of circle"?

Comment: @Nitish the requirement is to draw circle in 3D-space, using trigonometric functions.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to rotate the center of the circle. Or maybe some kind of "moon orbit", that cirulates around a center, which also circulates around another center? Or maybe just some kind of motion that circle around another point? Also it is possible to increase the orbital speed by increasing the angular velocity as well (`v = wr` should be used to customize the speed)

Comment: Yeah, U are very much right, I want the object cirulates around a center.

Comment: @patrik what should I do to implement such case in which an object just rotate the center of the circle (quoting ur words).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your requirement correctly, to draw a circle in 3 dimensions, you would need to specify the plane on which the circle rests. Let me assume that the plane is `z=1` plane.

So, you could plot a circle using:

```
t = 0:0.01:2*pi;
plot3(sin(t),cos(t),ones(size(t)));
```

Which gives this:

[image]

---

Bonus:

For a cool animation, try doing:

```
t = 0:0.01:2*pi;
comet3(sin(t),cos(t),ones(size(t)));
```

Comment: absolutely loved your bonus!!

Comment: its looking cool, but its just draw of circle along three coordinates, not the case that it rotates around center of the circle.

Comment: @AhsanAli, I apologize but I don't seem to understand what you mean by "rotates around center of the circle". When using polar coordinates, if you parametrize by the angle, then tracing a 2pi path (using sin and cosine with constant amplification factor) would yield a circle.

Comment: @Nitish let me explain U my scenario in real life example,  the motion of Radar in circular motion, the main object is it self not rotating, but around its center,  maybe some kind of "moon orbit".